# Controlling Overflow of Fixed Positioned Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to show items out of fixed positioned div. As shown in the picture half of the menu items are hidden inside the div. The vertical overflow is set to `scroll` but the horizontal overflow is set to `visible` but no items are visible outside the box.

I am not sure if this is even possible?

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #fefe
}
.bg-menu-container {
  background: black
}
.bg-menu-container {
    height: 140px;
    width: 200px;
position: relative;}

.bg-menu-container ul li a {
    display: inline-block
    padding: 10px 10px
    background: #dee
}

.bg-menu-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
overflow-x: visible;}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* WebKit */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.bg-menu-container .sub-menu {
 display: none;
  position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

}

.bg-menu-container ul li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-menu-container">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">  Home 00 </a><ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 00 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 03 </a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 03 </a><ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 00 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 03 </a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
Please scroll ...
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*[image: the view]

[image]
is that what you want? Try not to use *overflow* and *height* to him

And the code here:

```css
#myBody {
  background: #fefe
}
.bg-menu-container {
  background: black
}
.bg-menu-container {
    /* height: 140px; */
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* overflow-y: scroll; */
}

.bg-menu-container ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: #dee;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* WebKit */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.bg-menu-container .sub-menu {
 display: none;
  position: absolute;
    left: 140px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

}

.bg-menu-container ul li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="myBody">
    <div class="bg-menu-container">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">  Home 00 </a><ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 00 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 03 </a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Home 03 </a><ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 00 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 01 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 02 </a></li>
<li><a href="#">  Sub-Home 03 </a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
  </div>
</template>
```